# Building spice3f5 on OS X El Capitan

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, gcc

I'm trying to build spice3f5 on OS X El Capitan.

Not getting very far!

I try "util/build gcc" and it's weird, it seems to not like any of the shell commands with spaces in them and it seems to be expanding each symbol on a new line, and it can't find cat or make!:

```
grgs-iMac:Downloads grg$ cd spice3f5

grgs-iMac:spice3f5 grg$ ls

COPYRIGHT   examples    lib     man     msc51.bat   readme      util
conf        fixes       makedefs    manifest    notes       src

grgs-iMac:spice3f5 grg$ /bin/sh

sh-3.2$ util/build gcc

Begin build on grgs-iMac.local for gcc on Thu Jan 21 09:25:44 CST 2016:

Making "all" in spice3f5

/bin/sh: /bin/make: No such file or directory

make: [bootstrap] Error 127 (ignored)

Done with build at Thu Jan 21 09:25:44 CST 2016

sh-3.2$ echo $PATH

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

sh-3.2$ which make

/usr/bin/make

sh-3.2$
```

Comment: Do you need to run `configure` first? Mac OS X stores `make` in /usr/bin/make, but your attempt is trying to run `/bin/make`.

Comment: This code is from 2007, and is written assuming that you *port* the code before building on a new platform. OSX would be considered a new platform. Maybe trying the [macspice 3](http://www.macspice.com) package would be a better solution? I worked around the make problem by adding `MAKE=/usr/bin/make` in `conf/gcc`, and just ended up with a load of compilation errors.

Comment: Thanks, I did change MAKE= and fixed a lot of minor compilation errors.  Now it tries to link but there is NOTHING in Quartz X11 that looks like the needed entry points!